# Autodesk Platform Services Viewer limits

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm developing a web application similar to this https://inventor-config-demo.autodesk.io/.
If I deploy this application in a server, how many users can access the website, configure and view the model simultaneously. Can someone help me by sharing the limits/restrictions?

I haven't tried yet, just making an estimate for the product.

Answer (score 1):

> how many users can **access the website**, configure and **view the model** simultaneously

This will depend on where your web application is hosted. Cloud hosting providers such as AWS or Azure provide ways to scale out instances of your web server, but unless your app needs to handle tens of thousands of simultaneous connections, this probably won't be needed.

> how many users can access the website, **configure** and view the model simultaneously

A "configuration" in this context basically means sending a request to the Design Automation service to load, modify, and save a new version of a design file. The Design Automation service also adds and removes worker servers based on the length of the queue (and other factors), so that we can handle any amount of incoming tasks.